# Why is this global keyword not working in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

In the ascend() function, I use a global keyword to reference the Command variable, Changing it to "do 10 push-ups", However, when i print it, it appears to remain 'g' please help.

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()

Command = 'g'

icon = PhotoImage(file="gigachadFace.png")
ButtonImage = PhotoImage(file="DavidGoggins.png")

window.geometry("420x420")
window.title("GigaChad app")
window.iconphoto(True,icon)

title = Label(window, text="Welcome to the Gigachad App", font=("Arial", 40, "bold"), fg="#0011ff", bg="#00d0ff", bd=5, relief=SUNKEN)
title.pack()

def ascend():
    global  Command 
    Command = "Do 10 Push-ups"
print(Command)

Ascend = Button(window, text="Ascend", fg="black", bg="grey", activebackground="grey", activeforeground="black", command=ascend, image=ButtonImage, compound="bottom")
Ascend.place(x=475, y=250)

Order = Label(window, text=Command, bg="#00d0f0", fg="#0011ff", font=("Arial", 50, "bold"))
Order.place(x=600, y=500)

window.config(background="#00d0ff")

window.mainloop()
```

I can't find any other options

I would like to add that when I run the code, the Order label, doesn't display the updated command, is there a way to constantly check for updates?

Comment: Small Python note: variables are lower_snake_case. Don't call things `Command` when you mean `command`. It's not a class. with that said: you update it in a function called `ascend`, so where are you calling that function? (which is a hint, not a question)

Comment: `print(Command)` is outside of the function. It will run immediately before tkinter is even setup or you've pushed the button.

Comment: Unfortunately @Carcigenicate spoiled the "think about this a bit longer to see the problem all on your own" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, you just want to print out a value when you are clicking a button. Or also update a global variable?
In either case, the following code hopefully helps you out:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# Define your command as a variable
command = 'g'


def ascend():
    # Make your variable global if that is what you want
    global command
    command = "Do 10 push-ups"
    # Print your variable every time you call the function
    print(command)


# Note that now, everytime you press the button, the variable gets updated and printed
B1 = Button(root, bg="white", fg="black", font="none 12 bold", text="Click me", command=ascend)
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope this helps you out, and solves your problem, if you have any more questions, please let me know.